# How can I use a variable when setting an attribute with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I change the href content using below code in jquery. In addition, I want to add the page title after "subject=" with ".append", I don't know much about the syntax, so I make mistakes.

```
$("#mailbuton > div > div > div > a")
    .attr("href", "mailto:contact@site.com?subject='page title'");
```

`.append(document.title)` how should I use this code?

Comment: `.append` doesn't work on attributes

Comment: [jQuery append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is for adding/move DOM elements, not adjusting attribute strings.

Comment: So, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: *is there any other way to do it?* - not using `.append()` - why so fixated with .append?